# Expand Certain Div on Page Load with Link

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, expand

I have a page that has several divs that can expand/collapse on click. There are instances when I want to come to the page at an anchor spot with a certain div already expanded.

For example, one div is for a certain Video Series that is half-way down the page. I want to be able to share a link with someone so that they can come to the page anchored to this Video Series with the div already expanded to show the various modules within the Video Series.

Any help is appreciated! I've tried several different things, and nothing has worked.

HTML:

```html
<a name="TLS"></a> 

<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapsefoundationallearning" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapsefoundationallearning">Foundational Learning Video Series</a> <br>
                  
<div id="collapsefoundationallearning" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
<a href="">Module 1</a>
<br><a href="">Module 2</a>
<br><a href="">Module 3</a>
</div>
```

I tried this, but couldn't get it to work.

```
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var url = document.location.toString();
    if ( url.match('#') ) {
        var hash = url.split('#')[1];

        // collapse the expanded panel
        $('#accordion .accordion-collapse').removeClass('in');

        // expand the requested panel
        $('#' + hash).addClass('in');
    }
});
</script>
```

I also tried to find a way to change the class of a bootstrap div on page load by passing a parameter in the link, but I came up empty. I already have to pass the anchor and couldn't find anything about how to also pass a new class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with straight CSS, using [:target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target).  It'd look something like:

**HTML**

```
<div id="video-series">
  Content Here
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
:target {
  // styles for the target
}
```

Then in the link, add the `#video-series` to the end.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried display:block in the div:target, but that doesn't do anything. Can I change the class of the video-series div with CSS? I have class="panel-collapse collapse" for the div so that it'll be collapsed by default. I basically need to remove that class when the page loads and I use #video-series on the end of the link.

Comment: I think I may have misled, I don't think the `div` before the target is needed.  I did some testing in the browser, the JS you have _should_ work.  Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: It worked! I changed my CSS to match yours above, and it worked! Thank you! Now, how about getting the page to anchor to that div on page load? I added <a name="video-series"></a> above the div and in the div, and it broke the targeting that we just got working.

Comment: So, if you're link is to `#collapsefoundationallearning`, just add that `name= collapsefoundationallearning` to that element as well.  That _should_ link you to the spot with `name`, and then the `:target` should be styling the `#collapsefoundationallearning`.

Comment: That works. Thank you again! You've been a life saver. I marked your answer as the correct one. The only thing that isn't working now is my jQuery to collapse the panel once it has been expanded.

// collapse the expanded panel
$('#' + hash).removeClass('in');

Comment: I've narrowed it down at least. It's the :target { display:inline } that is not letting the div collapse. The jQuery is working; I looked at in with developer tools and the classes change correctly. I'm messing with the display CSS, but when I try others, like display: block, it collapses the div but leaves the text expanded.

Comment: Can you put the relevant stuff in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?  The `display:inline` won't collapse, because it can't use width and height.  If you put an `overflow:hidden` on the container with a display of `block` or `inline-block`, it should collapse _and_ hide the text.